# set default value in dynamic dropdown angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

please help me with my problem I'm a little new to angularjs, my problem is that I need to be able to set the default value in the select option when there is only one item because it's a dynamic select option, it has another dropdown with many items but it's okay , what is needed when only one item must be selected in the select option using ng-options

```
                    <select  class="form-control form"  ng-model="relatedTo" style="height: 40px;" ng-options="c.CUSTCODE as c.CUSTNAME + ' - ' + c.CUSTCODE for c in customers | filter:code" >  </select><span style="color:red" ng-show="type === 9 || type !== 9"></span>
```

ANGULARJS

```
                    $http.post('commandCenter.aspx/allCustomer', {}).then(
                        function onSuccess(response) {
                            $scope.customers = JSON.parse(response.data.d);
                            console.log($scope.customers); },
                        function onError(response) {
                            console.log('error !!! ');
                        });
```

Picture no.1 It's okay in this picture because he has a lot of list of items.

Picture no.2 When there is only one item, it must be default or selected.
[image]
[image]

Comment: You can check in your function, whether the array of options has the length of 1 or not. If so, then set the model value to the first item of the array. Other option you could do is to use ng-init in your html and always pick the first item of the array, so it can be your default selection

Comment: @MrJami I've already done this but what really needs to be done when there's only one item in the select should be automatically selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @MrJami said. In code something like

```
                $http.post('commandCenter.aspx/allCustomer', {}).then(
                    function onSuccess(response) {
                        $scope.customers = JSON.parse(response.data.d);
                        if ($scope.customers.length === 1) {
                          $scope.relatedTo = $scope.customers[0].CUSTCODE;
                        }
                        console.log($scope.customers); },
                    function onError(response) {
                        console.log('error !!! ');
                    });
```

Comment: it's not working for me

Comment: my idea here is to modified the select part like adding ng-if and anything   not in the controller but i don't know how to implement it.

Comment: What's the model value after you make a selection in the template? As far as I see, you need to set that value in the controller if the condition of a single option is fulfilled.

Comment: your code is working now thanks for the help, when I checked the inspect element the option value has been selected , the only problem that i have here is to remove the first blank option just like this <option value="?" selected></option> I dont know why is always selected.